# how can i solve this issue in my Django web application hosted on heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles

When a user upload a photo as a post it shows correctly on a home page but after sometime when user re-visit the website all photos that he\she posted do not show properly , i don't know whats the problem ?
[image]

How can i solve it ?

Comment: do the images still exist in the location they've been uploaded to?

Comment: Is there any way to see files on server of heroku ?

Comment: Just verify you Image Upload To method save path. Also, if you inspect the `img src` what path does it show?

Comment: If you ask a question it's expected that you will reply to comments. You have three comments already. I would like to add, have you looked at the chrome errors?

Comment: @Nagaraj  website locally works properly and path declared for upload is also correct .

Comment: @shuboy2014 so, then when you right click and inspect the element, just verify, the image twice, once when user uploads it first and then next when user views it. Take the url and paste it in the chrome url bar and see the difference in the url.

Comment: @Nagaraj now problem solved thanks for help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not store uploaded file (image) in Heroku. These will be lost when you restart or redeploy Heroku. If you want to support upload feature in your project, you can use [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to to that. And you can use this library [django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages)